# Highcharts not drawing lines between points

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

EDIT: The problem was that the intervals were inconsistent. Between this post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970233/how-to-access-javascript-array-values-within-a-setinterval-function) post, it can be fixed fairly easily.

I am using highcharts to draw a chart, with initial points being provided within the highcharts code, then the rest of the points are pulled in with ajax.

The initial points draw perfectly, and the first few fetched points also work fine, but every few minutes the points will stop being connected on the graph, then it will correct itself, then screw up again.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: That's the problem. I have literally no idea what could be causing it, so I don't really know where to look. I think there is a chance that the irregular intervals could be causing it, but im led to believe otherwise as it sometimes works with irregular intervals

Comment: I see no points in your picture that are connected. What does your data series look like? What is your HighCharts code? How are you fetching data?

Comment: This is how it looks when its working: http://imgur.com/vW3sz
I'm using the jquery ajax library to fetch the data, heres the fetch code http://pastebin.com/WbxC90pN

Comment: I am going to assume for now that it is the irregular intervals and take a stab at that. Based on the pastebin code I linked to, is there any way for me to access the series data from within the setinterval function. When I try it says something along the lines of undefined.

Comment: Okay, but what do you points look like? Are they always in chronological order? What does your chart code look like? Can you put up a jsFiddle with some sample data?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4dEZR7YL
Thats the full chart code, the fetched values are in the format:
time value value value
The new values are being pushed to the db every 5 seconds, and thats also the setinterval interval. I think what is happening is that on occasion the js is trying to fetch a value, expecting value number 4 but receiving value number 5, hence an irregular interval.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JUtx7mAh
Thats a pastebin of the initial values, I couldn't get jsFiddle working  with my code

Comment: could you post the code here itself, or even a non working jsFiddle is fine. Not everyone's (people like me) proxy allows them to connect to pastebin

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. My issue was that empty values (not zero, but a no-value-exists type scenario) were empty strings (""). Changing those values to null magically connected the dots for me.

Comment: I also had NaNs, which it also doesn't like.  Ditto on the change to null.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure that you have null instead of an empty string, etc, but also ensure you have enabled `connectNulls` in `plotOptions` as follows:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        connectNulls: true
    }
}
```

See [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-connectnulls-true/)

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! I only get this problem with logarithmic type. Linear seems to connect? Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I noticed that some of my 'empty' values were `undefined` and some were `null` values.
I changed it all to be `null` and it did the trick.