# How to access javascript array values within a setinterval function

Tags: javascript

How can I access the series data from within the function defined in setinterval. When I try to access any of the values, or even the array length, it says undefined.

```
events: {
                load: function() {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series0 = this.series[0];
                    var series1 = this.series[1];
                    var series2 = this.series[2];
                    var series3 = this.series[3];
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var y = $.ajax({url: "/index.php/control/fetch/<?php echo $uid; ?>",async: false}).responseText;
                            y = y.split(" ");
                        var x = parseInt(y[0]);
                        //alert("x = " + series0[0]);
                        //alert("len is " + parseInt(series0.length));
                        series0.addPoint([x, parseFloat(y[1])], true, true);
                        series1.addPoint([x, parseFloat(y[2])], true, true);
                        series2.addPoint([x, parseFloat(y[3])], true, true);
                        series3.addPoint([x, parseFloat(y[4])], true, true);

                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post more code? Your code seems fine, perhaps the problem is the original assignment, i.e., `var series0 = this.series[0]`.

Comment: Heres the full code http://pastebin.com/4dEZR7YL

Comment: @ethangk -- instead of editing the answer in to your question, simply add an answer.  It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a reference to **this** outside the callback function in setInterval. Something like this:

```
load : function() {
 ...
 var _self = this;
 setInterval(function() {
   console.log( _self.series );
 }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that allows me to access the series but it still kicks up a fuss when I try to do alert(self.series[0].length), claiming it is undefined. What I am trying to do is access the last x value of any of the series.

Comment: Also, why does referencing this outside the callback function cause it to work?

Comment: I have seen your code now and it's actually impossible to know from which object you can access series without guessing. You need to take a look at the documentation. Or do console.log(chart); and search for the series property somewhere inside the object by hand.

Comment: Think I found your problem. self.series[0] is an object, and it does not have the property length, and is therefor undefined. Try to alert( self.series[0].name ), you could also do a alert( self.series.length ) to find out how many "series" you have

Comment: Ahhhh you're right, I am so close to fixing the problem. self.series[0].data gives me access to the data from series 0, I just need to be able to access the x value of the last added item. I have:
self.series[0].data[self.series[0].length-1] but if I append .x or [0] onto the end of it, it kicks up a fuss

Comment: Ah, I made another stupid mistake.
self.series[0].data[self.series[0].data.length-1].x
Thats the final code required to access the value. Thanks!

Comment: self.series[0].data[self.series[0].data.length-1].x = '...'; :) (taking for granted that self.series[0].data is an array)

Comment: NITPICK: self is a bad variable name since [window.self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.self) refers to the current window.

Comment: Ah you're totally right, even though there were no risk for overwriting window.self in this case, thanks for nitpicking :)